# Compactness of sum of line segments in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f,g : \mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $f,g$ are continuous, and $\mathbb{X}$ is compact. Let $I_{x}$ be line segment with endpoints $(\cos(f(x))$, $\sin(f(x)),0)$ and $(0,0,g(x))$. Prove that $Z= \bigcup_{x \in X }$ $I_{x}$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^{3}$.

I only know that continuous functions on compact set has extreme values. Cos and sin are bounded functions. But what else? It isn't enough to the compactness

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the general form for an element of $Z$? What parameters does your formula depend on? What topological spaces do those parameters come from? Does this turn $Z$ into the image of some function? What can you say about this function?

Comment: This formula depends on two continuous functions and element of compact set. You mean that image of compact set under continuous function is a compact set?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing for you here is that compactness pushes forward under continuous maps. Also each individual line segment in your construction is compact. But then you're dealing with this infinite union $Z$, and the arbitrary union of compact things needn't be compact.

So here's a hint: see if you can rewrite $Z$ as the image of a map continuous $h: \mathbb{X} \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$. (The $[0,1]$ stands in for a line segment.)

Comment: You mean  t*$(\cos(f(x))$, $\sin(f(x)),0)$ + (1-t)* $(0,0,g(x))$?

Comment: That would do the trick.

Comment: But this is a formula for one line segment. What else?

Comment: I see a formula in both $t$ and $x$ right there!

Comment: Yes, because x belongs to $X$ and t belongs to $[0,1]$

Comment: So you've defined the map $\mathbb{X} \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: And that's all to show the compactness of Z?

Comment: You have a continuous map $h$. What topological property does its domain have? What is its image? What topological property can you conclude about its image?

Comment: A domain is a product of two compact spaces, image is an image under continuous map so it is... compact?

Comment: The product of compact spaces is compact. The continuous image of a compact set is compact.